# Removing rows that has 0's across multiple colum by retaining grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset that has zero's on all the column. I need to remove the rows that has zero's. But I would like to retain the other rows. Also, I do not want to disrupt the grouping variable.

```
Participant  Media B     C     D
A1           C11   0.5   0     0
A1           C12   0.4   0.3   0
A1           C13   0     0     0
A2           C11   0     0     0
A2           C12   1     2     0
A2           C13   2     0     0
```

I applied multiple filter function in `dplyr`. It does not help me with my dataset.

```
data <- data%>%
        filter(data, B > 0 & C > 0 & D >0)
```

Is there any quick way to subset the data without disrupting the dataframe?

Expected output

```
Participant  Media B     C     D
A1           C11   0.5   0     0
A1           C12   0.4   0.3   0
A2           C12   1     2     0
A2           C13   2     0     0
```

Comment: Are you asking to remove all rows that has at least 1 zero value in `B`, `C`, `D`? Or all values?

Comment: Try `df[rowSums(df[-c(1:2)] == 0) != ncol(df[-c(1:2)]),]`

Comment: Thanks @Sotos. akash87 - I just want to remove the row that has only 0's in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   filter_at(vars(B:D), any_vars(. != 0))
#  Participant Media   B   C D
#1          A1   C11 0.5 0.0 0
#2          A1   C12 0.4 0.3 0
#3          A2   C12 1.0 2.0 0
#4          A2   C13 2.0 0.0 0
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Participant = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
"A2"), Media = c("C11", "C12", "C13", "C11", "C12", "C13"), B = c(0.5, 
0.4, 0, 0, 1, 2), C = c(0, 0.3, 0, 0, 2, 0), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. This helped me remove unwanted rows and retain the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
subset(data,rowSums(data[-(1:2)])!=0)
```

such that

```
> subset(data,rowSums(data[-(1:2)])!=0)
  Participant Media   B   C D
1          A1   C11 0.5 0.0 0
2          A1   C12 0.4 0.3 0
5          A2   C12 1.0 2.0 0
6          A2   C13 2.0 0.0 0
```

Comment: Won't that fail if there's a +1 and a -1 in two columns?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ThomasIsCoding.